# Flex detect when mouse leaves a Canvas

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to detect when the mouse leaves a canvas. I know about the MOUSE_LEAVE, but this seems to only be valid for the stage, not Canvas objects.

take care,
lee

P.S. I have tried the mous-out, but, for some reason, that event keeps getting triggered everytime I move the mouse.

I should probably point out that I have used the Mouse.hide() and replaced the cursor with a custom cursor.

Comment: is it really every time you move the mouse or is it every time you hover over an object in your canvas?

Answer (score 4):

You could use either the `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` event or `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT`.

To see what is the difference and what you should use, [read this article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_What_is_the_difference_between_MouseOut_event_and-11906.html).

Comment: I believe you also need to set the canvas to have mouseEnabled="true" as I think it doesn't listen for mouse events by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`mouseOut` event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_OUT).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The trick was to set the custom cursor's parent to mouseChildren = false. Not a practical solution for most situations, but good for this.

The problem was coming from the fact that the mouse is still on the stage and moves slightly faster than the code move the custom mouse. So if the mouse was moved too quickly, it actually moved off the custom cursor.

take care,
lee

Comment: If you still want mouse children, then you need to use RollOut event. Mousechildren=false just tells the component not to register mouse events on child components.